# Add href text to link if clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, href

I have a page with several links. Some links point to the same exact URL. I want to add the text (the linkable href text) to the link that is clicked (or hovered?) when one of these duplicate links are clicked.

So far I can only seem to add the first link's text but not the one I click.

I have tried a few things but I am still learning JavaScript (I envy you all) and am afraid I keep messing it up the harder I try. I know I will likely have to use hover or somehow change `getElementsByTagName("a")[0]...` Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<p>
<a href="http://www.1.com" target="_blank">dog</a>
<a href="http://www.2.com" target="_blank">cat</a>
<a href="http://www.3.com" target="_blank">bird</a>
<a href="http://www.3.com" target="_blank">frog</a>
</p>
```

Javascript:

```
$var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a[href$="http://www.3.com"]');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(anchors, function (element, index) {
    element.href = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerHTML;
});
```

**Example**
When I click on the link "dog", I want to open a new browser tab/window with the URL of "http://www.1.com"

When I click on the link "cat", I want to open a new browser tab/window with the URL of "http://www.2.com"

When I click on the link "bird", I want to open a new browser tab/window with the URL of "bird"

When I click on the link "frog", I want to open a new browser tab/window with the URL of "frog"

So any link that has "http://www.3.com" as the href will ignore the "http://www.3.com" and instead open a new browser tab/window with the text that was just clicked.

Also, I am unable to add IDs, Class, script, etc. to the links/HTML so I have to figure out how to do all of this as JS referencing the href and not inside of the HTML.

Comment: so you want to add the href to the text of the element?

Comment: Your question isn't clear, you need to help us so we can help you. Make sure your read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't get it, are you just trying to do this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/s5t2vhsq/**

Comment: Abdul - more like replace the href withe the text (see my edits)
Pedro - Thanks and sorry, I'll try to be more clear in the future.
Adeneo - Sorry, I hope my edit/example will help clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague of mine found the solution. Thank's everyone for your help.

**Option 1:**

Replace part of my original JS:

"*document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerHTML*"

with:

"*window.location*"

Or

**Option 2:** [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chrsbrq/nz2r0sxs/6/)

Replace all of my original JS:

```
$var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a[href$="http://www.3.com"]');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(anchors, function (element, index) {
element.href = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerHTML;
});
```

With:

```
var anchors = $('a[href$="http://www.3.com"]');
$.each(anchors, function (index, element) {
$(element).attr('href',$(element).text());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
<a href="" onClick="javascript:this.innerHTML = 'ChangedClickMe'">ClickMe</a>
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/75prg1pm/)**

Comment: Thanks Rahul, but I would like to change what the final tab/window URL is. so in your example I would want a new tab/window to have the URL "http://ClickMe" instead of what was in the href="xx".

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're asking for but [THIS DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6nk51524/1/) is an example where I take the href and append it to the text.

html

```
<a href='#' onclick='change(this)'>link one</a>
<a href='#' onclick='change(this)'>link two</a>
<a href='#' onclick='change(this)'>link three</a>
<a href='#' onclick='change(this)'>link four</a>
```

css

```
a {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}
```

javascript

```
function change(variable) {
    variable.innerHTML = variable.innerHTML + variable.href;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Abdul, this is close, but I'm trying to change the new page/TAB/URL with the text i just clicked.  Sorry to be so confusing.